# PUT API loop with Json file

Tags: php, json

I'm building an API using PHP.
I want to PUT data from json file.
And  have a json file over 1000 SKU

```
{"data":[
{
  "sku": "ZT006V",
  "w_quantities": [
    {
     "w_id": 460,
     "qty": 10},
     {
      "w_id": 2454,
    "qty": 10}
  ]
},
{
    "sku": "ZT006XXX",
      "w_quantities": [
      {
      "w_id": 454,
      "qty": 12
      }]
}
]}
```

I do a PUT API command with ti.json content.
And I get error: 20 SKU limit per submission

```
$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => '/products/updateSkus',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'PUT',
  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS =>file_get_contents('ti.json'),
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer xxx',
    'Content-Type: application/json'
  ),
));
$response = curl_exec($curl)
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

I wonder, is there a way to send all 1000+ SKUs in the json file?
I searched the net, but no solution worked for me.
regards

Comment: Are you developing the api you're calling?

Comment: I looks like you are sending data to someone else's API. It also looks like that API has rules that you are breaking. Whoever owns the code at `updateSkus` is rejecting your data.

Comment: Sorry
I confused the json file. I mean SKU

Comment: I did it by looping it
$json = file_get_contents('file.json');
$objects = json_decode($json);
$partsx1 = array_slice($objects, 0, 20);
$parts1['data'] = $partsx1;
$partsx2 = array_slice($objects, 20, 20);
$parts2['data'] = $partsx2;
    for($i=1; $i < 10; $i++)
    {
  $N = ${'parts'.$i};
//Same as above 
CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => json_encode($N),
}
//Same as above

This is not the best way though.
But I think someone will need it like me.

Answer (score 0):

You manipulate the JSON File data on the fly using an array of numbers, which if number presents the ID, if I understand currently.

Comment: sorry I mean SKU not ID